# How to install package locally in bower?

Tags: bower, bower-install

I am trying to install a local Jquery ui through bower.

I have a local folder called `jquery-ui` and ran the following command

```
bower install jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css --save
```

It gave me the following errors

```
bower jquery-ui.min.css#*      resolve git://github.com/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css.git#*
bower jquery-ui.min.css#*      ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css.git", exit code of #128
```

I am not sure why bower look for the remove git, all I need is to add the local file into bower. Do I miss something here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try:

```
bower install ./jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css --save
```